# Css loading bar changes color

Tags: html, css, animation

Until now I have a simple loading bar:

```js
setInterval(tick, 10);
var width = 0;
function tick() {
    var el = document.getElementById('bar_full');
    width += 1;
    width = width > 97 ? 97 : width;
    document.getElementById('bar_full').style.width = width + '%';
}
```

```css
#bar_shell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: lightGray;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#bar_full {
    width: 0%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar_shell">
    <div id="bar_full"></div>
</div>
```

However, I would like it to change colors as it goes up. For example, when it is at 10%, it will be a dark green, at 50% it will start to turn yellow, and at 100% it will be red. I would like to solve this with css, but js is accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Css `annimation` , using key frames , see below snippet :

set also animation fill mode to `forwards` to maintain final annimation state .

```css
#bar_shell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: lightGray;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#bar_full {
    width: 0%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: changecolor 5s forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: changecolor 5s forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@-webkit-keyframes changecolor {
    0%   {width: 0; background:blue}
    25%  {width: 25%;background:yellow}
    50%  {width: 50%;background:orange}
    75% {width: 75%;background:red}
    100% {width: 100%;color:green}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes changecolor {
    0%   {width: 0; background:blue}
    25%  {width: 25%;background:yellow}
    50%  {width: 50%;background:orange}
    75% {width: 75%;background:red}
    100% {width: 97%;background:green}
}
```

```html
<div id="bar_shell">
    <div id="bar_full"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the background color depending on width. One way would be using an object with percentages and accompanying color:

```js
setInterval(tick, 10);
var width = 0;
var colors = {
  '0': '#cfeff0',
  '10': '#bbc6ce',
  '50': '#660066',
  '80': '#f6546a'
};
function tick() {
    var el = document.getElementById('bar_full');
    width += 1;
    width = width > 97 ? 97 : width;
    var el = document.getElementById('bar_full');
    el.style.width = width + '%';
    var color = colors[width];
    if (color) el.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
#bar_shell {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: lightGray;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#bar_full {
    width: 0%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar_shell">
    <div id="bar_full"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted only helps OP, without teaching them much. Therefore it encourages OP and other users to ask the same type of questions in the future and contributes to the demise of this website and, IMHO, does not help [so] *"make the web a better place"*, which is its mission statement. I admit I might be biased, but SO should not be a free coding service, but a place where one could learn and improve through (mostly) their own efforts.